# Hello World Node.js/Express application error

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I am learning MEAN stack so started with Node.js and Express first. I run Nginx on Windows 10. I installed the latest Node. NPM version is `3.10.3`, Node version is `6.7.0`, and Express version is `4.14.0`. I did `npm install express --save`, `npm install mongoose --save`, `npm install body-parser --save`, and created the server.js file. I did `node server` on my sources and I got the following error:

```
C:\nginx\html>node server
C:\nginx\html\server.js:7
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    ^

TypeError: app.get is not a function
    at Object. (C:\nginx\html\server.js:7:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

C:\nginx\html>
```

And the code in my server.js file is:

```
var express = require('express');
var express = require('mongoose');
var express = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(80);
```

I am not sure how a hello world application can go wrong. I saw a lot of tuts and code with the same thing but working for them. Even the Express's official hello world app has same code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose= require('mongoose');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(80);
```

Comment: EADDRINUSE  means that the port, 80 in this case, is already being used. So you can just change the port number, choose a higher number like 3000 or 8080.

Comment: yeah but 80 is the one my nginx is running. shouldn't both be same? i am sorry i come from php background so not much idea

Comment: @JackSlayer94 - No.  You run nginx on 80, and you configure it to forward to your node.js server on some other port and you run your node.js server on that other port number.  There can be only one server process listening on any given port.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `express` not `expression` as following

```
  npm install express --save
```

and then you like play

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
  res.json({data: req.body});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

and then try to listen another port that is above 1024 may be `3000` or `8080` or anything else otherwise you have to run cmd as Administrator

Comment: I'm pretty sure they meant Express, since the `expression` module does not have a 4.14.0 version.

Comment: I suppose @JackSlayer94 get confuse between express & expression otherwise we have to report bug in espress ):

Comment: @JackSlayer94 you have assigned `body-parser` in `express` variable that's why not working, have a look updated code